# Longer Cap of \sqrt

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am using ShareLaTeX for assignment.

I want to input an equation like:

```
$EOQ=Q^*=\sqrt(\frac{2K\lambda}{h})$
```

and got output like this:

[image: square root with short cap]

But I really want the square root with longer cap (or roof? I am not sure how to call it, and therefore I am not able to search the solution) like this:

[image: square root with long cap that cover the content in sqrt]

Wondering how I can fix that.

Comment: `\sqrt{\frac{2K\lambda}{h}}`, not `\sqrtsign(\frac{2K\lambda}{h})`. Notice the braces. I don't think `\sqrtsign` is documented anywhere; if it is recommended in some manual, throw it away.

Comment: Ahh... my bad, actually `\sqrt` also doesn't work... I will edit the post.

Comment: Emphasis on @egreg s comment part *Notice the braces* you have parentheses.

Comment: `\sqrt{}` should work. Could your limit your code to `\documentclass{<something>}\usepackage{<somepackage>}\begin{document}$EOQ=Q^*=\sqrt{\frac{2K\lambda}{h}}$\end{document}`?

Comment: Right, it is caused by the braces. Thank you both!

Answer (score 5):

The `\sqrt` command takes as a mandatory argument what's to be extracted the square root of.

So the correct syntax is

```
\sqrt{a+b}
```

not `\sqrt(a+b)`. Your problem is solved by using

```
Q^*=\sqrt{\frac{2K\lambda}{h}}
```

If you need the cube root (or other roots), there's the optional argument:

```
\sqrt[3]{a}
```

---

In a previous version of your question you had `\sqrtsign`: this macro actually exists for historical reasons, but is not documented and should not be used in documents.